# How to use dbcontext in Layout view (in .NET MVC, Entity framework)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

In my .NET (MVC, Entity framework) application I have some user rights in the database. For instance property "CanCreateNewContact". The "New contact" button I also have in page menu (in Layout view). I wonder how to hide this button if user doesn't have the necessary rights. In the classic view I can read the rights in the controller from the database (throught EntityFramework). But how to do it in the Layout view?

Comment: If it were me I'd think about creating a Navigation model. It is populated with links, etc. based on what rights a user has. Only what the user can access exists in the model. Then, your Navigation view is simply a rendering of said model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check a value in the ViewBag from your Layout View, and use a filter to set automaticaly the value based on your database (you don´t need to do this query on every action).

```
    public class UserRoleAttribute : FilterAttribute, IResultFilter
    {
        public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
        }
        public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            //You can do your stuff and set a viewBad value
            var ctx = new UserDbContext();
            var canDoSomething = ctx.Permissions.Any(x => ...);
            filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.CanDoSomething = canDoSomething;
        }
    }
```

Your layout will look like:

```
@{
    var canDomeSomething =  ViewBag.CanDoSomething !=null && (bool) ViewBag.CanDoSomething;
}
@if (canDomeSomething)
{
    <button></button>
}
else
{
    <span>Not button</span>
}
```

And your controller looks like:

```
    [UserRole]
    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know I can use Viewbag from standard controller in the Layout view.